# How to use .Value instead of .Select

Tags: excel, vba

does anyone have any insight on how to change this so I can just use value instead of select? I'm not sure how to incorporate it with the dynamic range, and when I did, it just populated in column A. Here's what I have:

```
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 2 To 325    

        Sheets("Cashflows").Range("A3").Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A" & I)

        Sheets("Cashflows").Range("A3:Z3").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Output").Range("A" & I).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Just do `Sheets("Cashflows").Range("A3:Z3").Copy`

Comment: `Sheets("Output").Range("A" & I & ":Z" & I).Value = Sheets("Cashflows").Range("A3:Z3").Value`